# Argument labels "(attributes:)" do not match any available overloads in DispatchQueue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I am trying to make the enemy in my game move using DispatchQueue. I tried fixing this error and it keeps telling me attributes do not match any available overloads.

```
 func makeAIMove() {
    let strategistTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()

    DispatchQueue.global(attributes: .qosUserInitiated).async { [unowned self] in

        guard let move = self.strategist.bestMoveForActivePlayer() as? Move else { return }

        let delta = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - strategistTime

        DispatchQueue.main.async{ [unowned self] in

            self.rows[move.row][move.col].setPlayer(.choose)

            let aiTimeCeiling = 2.0

            let delay = min(aiTimeCeiling - delta, aiTimeCeiling)

            DispatchQueue.main.after(when: .now() + delay) { [unowned self] in

                self.makeMove(row: move.row, col: move.col)

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is `DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated)`; indeed, there is no overload taking an `attributes` argument.